# spaces with isomorphic homotopy groups, though not homotopy equivalent

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Is there a way to prove that $S^2$ isn't homotopy equivalent to $S^3 \times \mathbb{CP^\infty}$ without homology theory? The tricky part is that all homotopy groups are isomorphic and I don't know many other homotopy invariants.

Comment: It's going to be difficult... My first guess was k-invariants of the Postnikov tower, but that uses homology (...because the k-invariants live in cohomology, and if homology is off-limits I assume cohomology is too). Why do you want to not use homology? It's a much simpler (to compute) invariant than homotopy groups.

Comment: There are hardly any other homotopy invariants, once you include more general cohomology theories. Is there any reason you want to do this?

Comment: @Kevin: there are plenty of other homotopy invariants (Whitehead brackets, Massey products), especially unstable ones, but they're just generally harder to compute.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Well, I was thinking of Brown representability, so certainly only stable things. But, sure, it's only true for an overly generous reading of "hardly."

Answer (score 7):

They can be distinguished by their [Whitehead brackets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_product). On any pointed space, there is a natural bilinear map

$$\pi_2(X) \times \pi_2(X) \to \pi_3(X)$$

and I claim that this map is nonzero on $S^2$ but zero on $S^3 \times \mathbb{CP}^{\infty}$. Roughly speaking, the point is that you've given the latter space nontrivial $\pi_2$ by just taking the direct product with $\mathbb{CP}^{\infty}$, and so this $\pi_2$ doesn't "talk to" the $\pi_3$ that you already had. The machinery of $k$-invariants is another way of making this precise, but this requires cohomology.

Proving this is harder than just computing homology or cohomology, though.

---

**Edit:** Actually, here's an easier argument that also makes precise the intuition that $\pi_2$ of the second space doesn't "talk to" any other part of it, but that doesn't use any additional machinery.

Suppose $f : S^2 \to S^3 \times \mathbb{CP}^{\infty}$ is a homotopy equivalence. Then it must induce an isomorphism on $\pi_2$, and hence $f$ must in fact be a representative of a generator of $\pi_2(S^3 \times \mathbb{CP}^{\infty})$. But such a generator factors through a map

$$\mathbb{CP}^{\infty} \to S^3 \times \mathbb{CP}^{\infty}$$

given by picking a point in $S^3$, and so $f$ must also factor (up to homotopy) as a composite

$$S^2 \to \mathbb{CP}^{\infty} \to S^3 \times \mathbb{CP}^{\infty}.$$

But such a map cannot induce an isomorphism on $\pi_3$, and hence can't be a homotopy equivalence; contradiction. This seems like a good example for building some intuition about why the hypothesis of the [Whitehead theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_theorem), that a map induces an isomorphism on all homotopy groups, is strictly stronger than the hypothesis that all homotopy groups are isomorphic.

Comment: Another reason that $f$ above can't exist is that every map $S^2 \to S^3$ is nullhomotopic.